# What is the genre of Outlander Season 4 opening credits?

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

The [theme for season 4](https://youtu.be/7_3yOsfA1tk) is  the [same song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-GdjUbNmW4) [as previously](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sECPEz5eDvc) [sung](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gvvu0eJZ14c) but given a thematic rehash based on the storyline for the season.

I was initially thinking it would be country but it is a bit different to the country music I am aware of.  Maybe American Folk?  I don’t know.

What music artists could I listen to who sing in this style?

Answer (score 3):

While **Contemporary Folk** is quite a good answer since the genre has the aspects of the theme song you're referring to, when we consider it as a "modern arrangement of folk music" as "PiedPiper" said.

I could also suggest sub-genres of **Americana** which is more focused on easy-listening and singer while trying to maintain the roots of folk music.

for example you can check out some **Scottish Americana** artists such as Lorkin O'Reilly or Roseanne Reid to see if this is what you seek for.

This platform usually doesn't like artist recommendation questions so you are probably going to help yourself at that part after you decide which characteristics from the theme song matches with which genre.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very old Scottish folk song called "Over the Sea to Skye", but with a more modern arrangement.
This is probably best described as ["Contemporary Folk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_folk_music).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  I know it is the *Skye boat song* but  **What is the genre of the arrangement?**

Comment: @ChrisRogers Modern or Contemporary  Folk